# What is the difference between vbscript and vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

What is the difference between vbscript and vb.net?

Comment: Related post - [What is the difference between VB and VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1384051/465053)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Except for sharing some syntax and keywords, they're quite different languages. [VBscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) is a very light weight language usually used for short scripts while [VB.Net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) is usually used to create full desktop or web applications.

You could try searching for `java vs javascript` and many of those pages will describe differences between a scripting language and a normal programming language, javascript is similar to vbscript and java is similar to vb.net.

Answer (score 3):

VBScript is a scripting language that is used mainly for doing small automated jobs.

The most powerful Windows technology is the .NET Framework. Visual Basic has been modified to be a true object-oriented language when working with the .NET Framework and that syntax is called VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

**VB Script**:

Quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1384065/465053) answer:

> VBScript is a sub-set of VB and is a scripting language that can be
>   used to run a set of commands, similar to an old-school DOS batch
>   file. Generally, a scripting language can not be used to create a
>   full-fledged binary application and it can not be compiled down to a
>   executable binary file.

vb script has been used a lot in writing plugins and extensions for browsers in the past. Browsers were capable to interpret the vb script.

**Visual Basic .NET (aka VB .NET)**

On the other hand, Visual Basic .Net was a progression of the Visual Basic language to target the common language run-time (CLR) which is the virtual execution environment (like JVM in java) of .NET framework based applications.

Historically when .NET framework came up, Microsoft introduced a completely new language C# (to compete with Java) but since most of the programmers following MS technologies were from Visual Basic background MS decided to have VB .NET option as well in parallel with C# .NET. This way for VB programmers it didn't become a binding to learn a completely new language (C#) syntax from scratch to start writing new applications targeting .NET framework.

**Compilation logistics of VB series of languages** :

*Visual Basic* => Compiled to native code packaged inside *.dll or *.exe files.

*VB script* => An interpreted language. It is not compiled. You can get more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42569227/465053)

*Visual Basic .NET* => VB .NET is compiled to MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language) code (similar to byte code in Java world) packaged inside *.dll or *.exe files.