# VBScript Expected end of statement when declaring an integer

Tags: excel, vbscript, integer

I keep receiving an error on line 2 char 9 with the error

> Expected end of statement.

I am new to working with VBScript but I have looked up several examples and I can not find where I am having an error on that line. Can you guys assist?

Edited for more info:
If I remove the Dim row As Integer line running the script give me a type mismatch error. 
If I remove row = 150 and replace row further down with 150 the script updates the excel sheet as expected.

```
Dim args, objExcel
Dim row As Integer 'I am having the error here. Note this comment is not normally here.

row = 150
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\gria\Desktop\Test\GrossRevenueCopy.xlsm"
objExcel.Visible = False

objExcel.Run "InsertRow", row

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: What application / programming language is this code being written in?

Comment: I first did it in Notepad++ and then thought that may be the issue so I also tried it in the windows Notepad but same error no change.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this in Excel 2013 - It complained that the instructions were not in a procedure, so I put everything from `row=150` and below into a `Public Sub foo()` . It worked fine for me. Need some clarification to better help you.

Comment: Note that this comment uses C# syntax; VBA comments are denoted by either a single-quote, or a `Rem` instruction.

Comment: But after having written it in Notepad, what application / programming language / development environment are you running it in?

Comment: How about using the VBE instead of Notepad?

Comment: @Mat'sMug that was to just throw out a comment. I am new to VBA so i just used java style comments. Those comments are not in the script when I try to run it

Comment: Is this an entire module's code? Because most of that code is only legal inside a procedure scope.

Comment: @YowE3K I save it as a .VBA file then I activate it by double clicking the file. End game is to pass a row number from a java application to this script to update this excel file.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes this is the entire code.

Comment: OK, so you are trying to run it as VBScript.  Get rid of the `As Integer` then.

Comment: Then it's not VBA, it's VBScript. VBA requires executable statements to be inside a procedure scope - @YowE3K, it's all yours =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Your right VBScript. My bad T_T

Comment: @YowE3K I edited the original question where I tried to do that. I get a type exception error.

Comment: @Mat'sMug As soon as I see things like `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` my first thought is "This is not Excel VBA (even if it is using the Excel Object Model)".  Usually it ends up being Word VBA, or MSAccess VBA, but the complaint about the word `As` caused red flags to be raised.

Comment: @YowE3K agreed. I had to add my grain of salt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44168928/1188513).

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the help and your link. Helped me understand these differences, and the original error, much clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBScript does not have the concept of a variable "type", so it complains if you try to define something `As Integer`.

So the simple solution is to replace

```
Dim row As Integer
```

with

```
Dim row
```

Comment: When I edit the code to match I get the error Type mismatch on line 10, code: 800A000D

Comment: @Ardel Try converting the parameter to an integer using `CInt(row)`.  Note: I don't use VBScript, so I am guessing as to whether it includes a `CInt` function.  Or change your `InsertRow` function to accept a `Variant` or an `Object` (depending on what type VBScript actually uses for its variables).

Comment: Would be `Variant`, given `row` is definitely not an `Object` reference.

Comment: @YowE3K chaing = row to = CInt(row) fixes all the issues and does exactly what I need. Thank you for all your help and patience

Comment: @Mat'sMug I wasn't sure whether VBScript might be like VB.Net where everything is an object, even basic data types.  (So in VB.Net `Dim x As Integer = 5: MsgBox x.ToString` is valid because `x` is an object which has a `ToString` method.)